# EF Core извлечение уровней вложенности из обобщенного репозитория

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день! Необходимо из БД вытащить несколько уровней вложенности:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProduct()
    {
        return _appContext.Products
            .Include(o => o.ProductCategory)
            .Include(o => o.ProductPhotos)
            .Include(o => o.Сharacteristics)
                .ThenInclude(op=>op.Property)
            .Include(o => o.Descriptions)
            .Include(o => o.ChildrenProduct);
    }
```

Я хочу использовать обобщенный метод:

```
   public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = _context.Set<T>();

        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty); // ???.ThenInclude(op=>op.Property) ???

        return dbQuery.AsNoTracking();
    }
```

Но не могу вытащить 2рой уровень вложенности, в коде выше используется ThenInclude(???), как использовать это здесь? 
Простите это мой первый вопрос..